# How to pause a running program in R studio?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I want to run a program which uses genetic algorithm. I'm processing 50 generations of 10,000 rules for 2000 iterations (stopping criteria). So, the time it takes is a lot. For the case of 4 generation and 4 iterations it took 30 minutes. How can I pause the running of such program at a certain iteration without losing the output of the algorithm before that iteration?
Can I put the result in stack ( like what we do in assembly language) or does R studio provide an option for my problem?
Any suggestion would be appreciated too.

Comment: If your code is sourced (source("myfile.R")), you can set a break point as in Visual Studio or Eclipse. RStudio will show a message if a break point is set without sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to "pause" every 4 generations.
In your code, add something like this

```
if (generation %% 4 == 0) browser()
```

This will pause execution every 4 generations and give you debugging control, so you can inspect to see what's the state of everything, and continue without losing any data when you are ready.  Maybe not exactly what you had in mind, but certainly an option.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively a convenient way may involve using `readline`:

```
fun <- function() {
  ANSWER <- readline("Are you a satisfied R user? ")
  ## a better version would check the answer less cursorily, and
  ## perhaps re-prompt
  if (substr(ANSWER, 1, 1) == "n")
    cat("This is impossible.  YOU LIED!\n")
  else
    cat("I knew it.\n")
}
if(interactive()) fun()
```

or `Sys.sleep` if you want to suspend the execution for a number of seconds:

```
testit <- function(x)
{
    p1 <- proc.time()
    Sys.sleep(x)
    proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}
testit(3.7)
```